# Getting None type error from a valid regex query

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the value of `os` (`Linux 3.11 and newer`) from a program's output. I came up with this:

```
import re

p0f = '''
--- p0f 3.08b by Michal Zalewski <lcamtuf@coredump.cx> ---

[+] Closed 3 file descriptors.
[+] Loaded 324 signatures from '/etc/p0f/p0f.fp'.
[+] Will read pcap data from file 'temp.pcap'.
[+] Default packet filtering configured [+VLAN].
[+] Processing capture data.

.-[ 10.0.7.20/37462 -> 216.58.209.229/443 (syn) ]-
|
| client   = 10.0.7.20/37462
| os       = Linux 3.11 and newer
| dist     = 0
| params   = none
| raw_sig  = 4:64+0:0:1460:mss*20,7:mss,sok,ts,nop,ws:df,id+:0
|
`----

.-[ 10.0.7.20/37462 -> 216.58.209.229/443 (mtu) ]-
|
| client   = 10.0.7.20/37462
| link     = Ethernet or modem
| raw_mtu  = 1500
|
`----


All done. Processed 1 packets.
'''


print p0f
os = re.match(r"os\\s*= (.*)", p0f).group(1)
print os
```

According to this [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bI4aO8/1), my regex should be spot on. But I'm getting an error `NoneType has no 'group'`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Answer (score 5):

You have two problems:

- You are using `re.match()` where you should be using `re.search()`. `re.match()` only matches against the *start* of the string. See [`search()` vs. `match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) in the module documentation.
- You doubled the `\\` backslash on the `\s` metacharacter, but are using a `r'..'` raw string literal.

This works:

```
re.search(r"os\s*= (.*)", p0f)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"os\s*= (.*)", p0f).group(1)
'Linux 3.11 and newer'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `r`, don't escape the `\`. This works:

```
re.search(r"os\s*= (.*)", p0f).group(1)
```